# Spark process unstructured files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I had a question regarding processing unstructured files located in HDFS using Spark.

Let's say in this scenario, we have a lot of files located in one HDFS folder. So, the Spark application will read all files in that particular HDFS folder and process it. My question here is if we were to use the following codes to read the files and place it in DataFrame, it might hit out of memory issue if HDFS folder contains lots of files and each file has huge size:

```
df = spark.read.text('/user/tester/datafiles')
```

What is the best practice or approach for us to process HDFS files like the scenario above? Is it we need to loop file by file and process it instead of read all the files at one go?

Thanks.

Comment: i don't think you need to do anything as files are stored as block of 128 mb in hdfs and second is spark will fetch only that amount of memory which it can process in given memory otherwise you have the option of repartion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points to understand

1) spark.read.text is an transformation. It will not trigger data read.

2) The operations for converting the data to DataFrame can also be transformation. So data loading can be avoided.

3) Finally if you perform some operation, lets say count().

- A job will be created.
- This job will be divided in to multiple stages based on shuffle boundaries.
- Each stage will be further divided in to multiple tasks based on partitions.
- Now tasks will be executed based on available executors core/node!!!

Now, as #Akash already told, for HDFS, files are already stored in blocks. The default partitioning for spark creates a partition in rdd per block. So any point, only few blocks will be loaded for processing.

Comment: Thanks Akash Sethi and Rakesh. Meaning to say that Spark will handle the memory with the processing part itself and it will less likely to hit "out of memory" issue? If the core and memory allocated for that particular spark job, then it will take longer time to complete rather than hitting exception, right?